# Why is rsync so much slower than my Python script for syncing?

Tags: windows-10, performance, python, rsync, msys2

I have the following Python script that I sometimes use to mirror large directories (main logic for syncing is implemented within `sync_directory()`). It also tries to mirror other metadata such as file creation/modification/access times:

```python
# Standard library full imports
import hashlib
import shutil
import stat
import sys
import os
# Related third-party full imports
import docopt
# Standard library partial imports
from pathlib import Path

"=================================================================================================="
"Constants"

# Command line interface for docopt
USAGE_MSG = """
MySync

Precisely mirror <src_dir> in <dst_dir>.

Usage:
  mysync.py [options] <src_dir> <dst_dir>
  mysync.py -h | --help

Options:
  -d --show-deletions  Show any deletions that occur within <dst_dir>.
  -h --help            Show this screen.
"""

"=================================================================================================="
"Helper Functions - Rmtree On-Error"

def rmtree_onerror(func, path, excinfo):
    """Handle instances of paths not being properly deleted.
    
    Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59507412
    """
    
    os.chmod(path, stat.S_IWRITE)
    
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        os.rmdir(path)
    else:
        os.remove(path)

"=================================================================================================="
"Helper Functions - Set Creation Time"

"""
Source for this section:
https://github.com/Delgan/win32-setctime/blob/master/win32_setctime.py
"""

try:
    from ctypes import byref, get_last_error, wintypes, FormatError, WinDLL, WinError

    kernel32 = WinDLL("kernel32", use_last_error=True)
    
    CreateFileW = kernel32.CreateFileW
    SetFileTime = kernel32.SetFileTime
    CloseHandle = kernel32.CloseHandle

    CreateFileW.argtypes = (
        wintypes.LPWSTR,
        wintypes.DWORD,
        wintypes.DWORD,
        wintypes.LPVOID,
        wintypes.DWORD,
        wintypes.DWORD,
        wintypes.HANDLE,
    )
    CreateFileW.restype = wintypes.HANDLE

    SetFileTime.argtypes = (
        wintypes.HANDLE,
        wintypes.PFILETIME,
        wintypes.PFILETIME,
        wintypes.PFILETIME,
    )
    SetFileTime.restype = wintypes.BOOL

    CloseHandle.argtypes = (wintypes.HANDLE,)
    CloseHandle.restype = wintypes.BOOL
except (ImportError, AttributeError, OSError, ValueError):
    SUPPORTED = False
else:
    SUPPORTED = os.name == "nt"


def setctime(filepath, timestamp, *, follow_symlinks=True):
    """Set the "ctime" (creation time) attribute of a file given an unix timestamp (Windows only)."""
    
    if not SUPPORTED:
        raise OSError("This function is only available for the Windows platform.")

    filepath = os.path.normpath(os.path.abspath(str(filepath)))
    timestamp = int(timestamp * 10000000) + 116444736000000000

    if not 0 < timestamp < (1 << 64):
        raise ValueError("The system value of the timestamp exceeds u64 size: %d" % timestamp)

    atime = wintypes.FILETIME(0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF)
    mtime = wintypes.FILETIME(0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF)
    ctime = wintypes.FILETIME(timestamp & 0xFFFFFFFF, timestamp >> 32)

    flags = 128 | 0x02000000

    if not follow_symlinks:
        flags |= 0x00200000

    handle = wintypes.HANDLE(CreateFileW(filepath, 256, 0, None, 3, flags, None))
    if handle.value == wintypes.HANDLE(-1).value:
        raise WinError(get_last_error())

    if not wintypes.BOOL(SetFileTime(handle, byref(ctime), byref(atime), byref(mtime))):
        raise WinError(get_last_error())

    if not wintypes.BOOL(CloseHandle(handle)):
        raise WinError(get_last_error())


"=================================================================================================="
"Helper Functions - Sync Directory"

def sha256_file_hash(file):
    """Get SHA-256 checksum of a file"""
    
    # Buffer of given byte size (for checksum())
    BUFFER_SIZE = 64 * 1024 * 1024 #64 megabytes
    
    hash_obj = hashlib.sha256()
    with open(file, 'rb') as file:
        while (data := file.read(BUFFER_SIZE)):
            hash_obj.update(data)
    
    return hash_obj.hexdigest()


def sync_directory(src_dir, dst_dir, show_deletions=False):
    """Backup dir by only copying/deleting files as needed (similar to rsync)"""
    
    src_dir = str(src_dir)
    dst_dir = str(dst_dir)
    
    if not os.path.exists(dst_dir):
        os.mkdir(dst_dir)
    
    # List of names found ONLY in dst_dir (will be trimmed down)
    dst_dir_only_names = set(os.listdir(dst_dir))
    
    try:
        src_dir_names = os.listdir(src_dir)
    except PermissionError as exc:
        print(f'INFO: os.listdir() raised error trying to access "{str(src_dir)}"')
        print(f"=> {exc}")
        src_dir_names = []
    
    for src_name in src_dir_names:
        
        # Already found in src_dir, so not unique to dst_dir
        if src_name in dst_dir_only_names:
            dst_dir_only_names.remove(src_name)
        
        src_path = os.path.join(src_dir, src_name)
        dst_path = os.path.join(dst_dir, src_name)
        
        # Base case: src_path is for a file
        if os.path.isfile(src_path):
            
            if not (
                os.path.exists(dst_path) and
                os.path.isfile(dst_path) and
                os.path.getsize(dst_path)  == os.path.getsize(src_path) and
                os.path.getmtime(dst_path) == os.path.getmtime(src_path)
                ):
                
                # Try to copy file, as well as metadata (ctime, mtime, atime)
                try:
                    shutil.copy2(src_path, dst_path)
                
                # May occasionally generate OSError (or subclass thereof)
                # But these will be considered "spurious" if all content was copied
                except OSError as exc:
                    
                    print(f'INFO: shutil.copy2() raised error copying "{str(src_path)}"')
                    print(f"=> {exc}")
                    
                    # Can continue normal operation as long as both files have same contents
                    # Either shutil.copy2() partially succeeded, or both files already same
                    if (
                        os.path.exists(dst_path) and
                        os.path.isfile(dst_path) and
                        os.path.getsize(dst_path)  == os.path.getsize(src_path)  and
                        sha256_file_hash(src_path) == sha256_file_hash(dst_path) ):
                        print("=> But files have matching content")
                    
                    # If contents not same, copying operation definitely failed
                    else:
                        
                        # Can still continue trying to copy other files
                        # No need to re-raise, just print for user to see
                        print(f'=> Couldn\'t copy file: "{src_path}"')
                        continue #to next src_path
                
                # Make sure dst_path's ctime same as src_path
                # setctime() might be expensive, so check if needed first
                src_ctime = os.path.getctime(src_path)
                dst_ctime = os.path.getctime(dst_path)
                if src_ctime != dst_ctime:
                    setctime(dst_path, src_ctime)
                
                # Make sure dst_path's atime/mtime same as src_path
                os.utime(dst_path, (
                    os.path.getatime(src_path), 
                    os.path.getmtime(src_path)))
                
                # Let user know if any file times still don't match (highly unusual)
                for attr_name in ("ctime", "mtime", "atime"):
                    getxtime = getattr(os.path, f"get{attr_name}")
                    if getxtime(src_path) != getxtime(dst_path):
                        print(f"INFO: {attr_name} mismatch: {src_path!r}")
        
        # Use recursion to sync sub-directories
        elif os.path.isdir(src_path):
            sync_directory(src_path, dst_path, show_deletions=show_deletions)

    # Remove all paths that were only found in dst
    for dst_name in dst_dir_only_names:
        
        dst_path = os.path.join(dst_dir, dst_name)
        
        if show_deletions:
            print(f'Deleting "{dst_path}"...')
        
        if os.path.isfile(dst_path):
            os.remove(dst_path)
        elif os.path.isdir(dst_path):
            shutil.rmtree(dst_path, onerror=rmtree_onerror)
    
    # Can only reliably set atime/mtime after modifying dir itself
    os.utime(dst_dir, (os.path.getatime(src_dir), os.path.getmtime(src_dir)))

"=================================================================================================="
"Main"

def main():

    # Set up interface for docopt
    args = docopt.docopt(USAGE_MSG)
    
    src_dir = Path(args["<src_dir>"]).absolute()
    dst_dir = Path(args["<dst_dir>"]).absolute()

    show_deletions = args["--show-deletions"]
    
    sync_directory(src_dir, dst_dir, show_deletions=show_deletions)


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

The reason I wrote this script is because when I try to do something equivalent to it with `rsync`, it's **much** slower. This is using `rsync` within MSYS2 (mingw64), but I've noticed similar results with `rsync` within WSL2 as well (so it has something to do with how `rsync` itself works).

I'm currently running:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.11.4
- rsync version 3.2.7 (in MSYS2)

**Example:**

I was mirroring my 27 GB Documents directory (~145,000 files, 17,000 folders) to an external HDD. Just as a base test, both the source and mirror have already been synced prior (although I get similar results even if a few files have changed).

Using `rsync`, it seems to have gotten stuck around 6 minutes in, and I manually stopped it after **33 minutes**. I suspect it would have completed eventually (I've used the same invocation for other sync jobs before), but I don't know how long it would have taken:

```
$ C:\msys64\usr\bin\rsync.exe ^
    --archive ^
    --delete ^
    --whole-file ^
    --partial ^
    --times ^
    --crtimes ^
    --atimes ^
    --verbose ^
    --progress ^
    --info=progress2,name0 ^
    "C:/path/to/Documents" "E:/path/to/DocumentsBackup"
sending incremental file list
...
      4,147,432   0%   10.80kB/s    0:06:11 (xfr#6, ir-chk=1001/54912)
rsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(713) [sender=3.2.7]
```

For the same sync job, my Python script completed in **88 seconds**.

I have two questions:

1. Why is `rsync` so much slower than my Python script (i.e. what are they doing so differently)?
2. How can I achieve the functionality **and** performance of my python script using `rsync` (or `cp`, or a similar util)?

**IMPORTANT:** I would greatly prefer if the chosen util/approach also works in Linux, as I'm currently trying to migrate away from Windows.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE #1:** I know it's not easy to update crtimes on Linux file systems. So any solution that can at least preserve access/modification times is fine as well.

**UPDATE #2:** Well, this is unexpected.

I decided to test the `rsync` and `mysync.py` approaches on my Linux Mint dual boot. I already had a slightly older copy of my Documents folder in the Linux system (because I'm migrating). I tried syncing from the external HDD to the Documents dir in Linux (some files had been changed since previously). The only thing I changed in the rsync invocation was removing the `--crtimes` flag (seems like it's not supported in my Linux Mint `rsync`):

```
$ time rsync --archive --delete --whole-file --partial --times --atimes --verbose --progress --info=progress2,name0 /media/user/hdd/Documents/ ~/Documents/
sending incremental file list
...
  3,061,695,271  10%   10.87MB/s    0:04:28 (xfr#81200, to-chk=0/162233)   

sent 3,070,547,352 bytes  received 1,777,891 bytes  11,357,949.14 bytes/sec
total size is 28,796,538,110  speedup is 9.37

real    4m30.102s
user    0m12.905s
sys 0m48.600s
```

Running `rsync` in a real Linux system, it took **4m30s** the first time. Since they were now synced up, I tried it again to see if it would be faster/slower a second time:

```
$ time rsync --archive --delete --whole-file --partial --times --atimes --verbose --progress --info=progress2,name0 /media/user/hdd/Documents/ ~/Documents/
sending incremental file list
              0   0%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#0, to-chk=0/162233)   

sent 4,544,474 bytes  received 20,350 bytes  212,317.40 bytes/sec
total size is 28,796,538,110  speedup is 6,308.36

real    0m21.466s
user    0m1.439s
sys 0m6.301s
```

This time only **21 seconds**. Lastly, for comparison I tried `mysync.py` (specifically, an adapted version that just doesn't have any `setctime()` function).

```
$ time python jsync.py /media/user/hdd/Documents/ ~/Documents/

real    2m24.725s
user    0m5.298s
sys 0m35.002s
```

It took **2m24s** (and this is actually the second run, somehow on the first one it seemed stalled, so I manually stopped it after **3 minutes**).

**Conclusion**: `rsync` is far slower than `mysync.py` on Windows + MSYS2, but this is somehow
nearly **reversed** on a real linux system.

The good news for me is that I can just keep using `mysync.py` for now, and then simply use `rsync` when I've migrated to Linux. **However**, I'm leaving this question open in case anyone else still needs `rsync` to work for them in MSYS2. I myself would still like to know what causes this massive performance difference on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation is that running the script or `rsync` once
loaded the metadata of the two concerned directories into memory
so that future runs were much faster.

This theory holds water only if you have a very large number of
files in the directories.

Comment: Testing out this theory, I restarted Windows to clear the memory, and used `mysync.py` to sync the Documents folder to the external drive again, which completed in **8m11s** (I pre-synced everything before the restart, to ensure both approaches had a fair comparison). Then I *restarted again* and tried the `rsync` approach; it seemed to get stuck around 7m33s, and I manually stopped it after **40 minutes**.

Comment: The conclusion is is either a bug in `mysync.py` or a problem with the sync target. Check resources use in Windows (Task Manager and Resource Monitor) before and after running it. A program of yours might be less of a proof than a well-known product.